# Cannot see Databases In Visual Studio SQL Server Object Explorer after previous database dropped

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I used to be able to see all databases in the SQL Server Object Explorer in Visual studio 2012. I dropped one of the main databases that I used to work with in VS, now I can no longer see any of the other databases.

I can connect to the Server (SQL Server 2012) but the database tree is empty.

***Screen shot:***

[image]

How do I restore seeing the databases?

Answer (score 5):

I am posting the answer after 5 years as this potential bug is still a repro with VS2019. Apparently the issue seems to be with the database selected while adding the server.

To solve this issue, leave the database name to default as below. I will be following up with the VS team in the meantime.

[image: Don't select anything on the default database]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, found the answer:

I needed to set a default database in SQL Server using Management Studio.

As soon as I did this and connected to a server in Visual Studio, the databases appeared in the Object Explorer in Visual studio.

How to set the default database: You simply go to: Security --> Select your login --> properties --> select default database.